# AWS EC2 responds with HTTP 502 when trying to upload media file

Tags: amazon-ec2, tomcat7, image-uploading, amazon-rds

I'm using an `AWS EC2` instance (associated with a load balancer) to host my server code that connects to the database on `AWS RDS`.

An `Android` app is one of the clients to the server and connects using the `HttpUrlConnection`. When the app makes a `POST` call to upload an encoded media file, there is a long waiting time to get the response from the EC2 server instance. Also, when a response was received, it was a **HTTP 504**. So I worked on increasing the **Idle timeout** value of the EC2 instance to 600 seconds after which I'm getting a **HTTP 502**, due to which the Health state of the `Elastic Beanstalk` application switches to either **Warning** or **Critical**.

To cross check my server code, I used a `Localhost Tomcat v7.0` server ( something like a http://localhost:8080/abc/...) to upload the same data using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/), I get a success and **HTTP 201**. So now I am clear that there are no issues with the server code.

But when I try to reach the AWS endpoint through Postman, I get the same HTTP 502 as below:

[image]

Would it be something to do with the configurations on EC2/Load balancer or the RDS itself?

Answer (score 1):

The error is probably exactly what it says: the proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server. Is there a way for you to see exactly what is being sent to the proxy server? If you can't see anything, on your EC2 instance, try setting 
    ProxyBadHeader Ignore
in your httpd.conf. That way you can see if Apache is ignoring the data because some errors got put in place of a header. Your case sounds very familiar to: http://blog.somepixels.net/en/502-proxy-error-uploading-from-apache-mod_proxy-to-tomcat-7/

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I followed [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20160421042123/http://blog.somepixels.net:80/en/502-proxy-error-uploading-from-apache-mod_proxy-to-tomcat-7/) link provided by @Eddimull as mentioned above to configure the Timeout and proxy headers. Also on my server code, on a successful upload (POST) , I was returning back the data that was aimed to be uploaded as part of the response. This meant that I had to send back the encoded media file as part of the response due to which I was I was stuck with the **Invalid Response** . Instead, now I am sending a response which is simpler and this solved the issue.